# using .split() to take out and modify certain parts of a string, modifying and displaying them differently JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to split the 'Example Response' and 'Example Request' from a response I'm getting in a markdown file, and want to display them in h3 tags on my html page, but I don't know how I can .split() using JavaScript because I can't write a script to delete a certain number of characters ahead since there will be other responses that will be different.

Example Request:

https://somelink.com/

Example Response:

```
{
  head: { .... },
  data: [
    {
      blah: "bl4h, blah, bl4h"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you split using `split()` I don't get the question

Comment: The input you are working with is unclear. Does it actually have "Example Response:" in it?

Comment: yeah unfortunately, it actually has the 'Example Response' written in it, and I'm trying to separate it out, so I can have the actual response in <pre> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to *split* the response (at the position of e.g. `Example Request`) but select different parts of it and show them differently. A great use case for [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
function parse(raw) {
  var elements = raw.match(/(.|[\r\n])*(Example Request)((.|[\r\n])*)(Example Response)((.|[\r\n])*)/i).slice(2);
  console.log(elements);
  return '<h3>' + elements[0] + '</h3><p>' + elements[1] + '</p><h3>' + elements[3] + '</h3><pre>' + elements[4] + '</pre>';
}

document.getElementById('action').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var raw = document.getElementById('text').value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parse(raw);  
});
```

```css
textarea { display: block; width: 100%; height: 5em; }
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea><button id="action">render</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

It's actually quite tricky. You have to match newlines as well (`(.|[\r\n])`), this generates unnecessary groups (the jump from `elements[1]` to `elements[3]`). See this as a first hint, there are lot things that should never make it into productive code.